# Collecting hashes into OpenStruct creates "table" entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why this (evaluated in Rails console)

```
[{:a => :b}].collect {|x| OpenStruct.new(x)}.to_json
```

adds a "table" record in there?

```
"[{\"table\":{\"a\":\"b\"}}]
```

I want just this:

```
"[{\"a\":\"b\"}]
```

Does it mean that Rails' to_json method handles OpenStruct in a different way? When I try it in the irb, it's not there:

```
require 'ostruct'
[{:a => :b}].collect {|x| OpenStruct.new(x)}.inspect
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `marshal_dump`, although this somewhat defeats the purpose of converting it to an OpenStruct beforehand:

```
[{:a => :b}].collect {|x| OpenStruct.new(x).marshal_dump }.to_json
=> "[{\"a\":\"b\"}]"
```

The shorter way would be:

```
[{:a => :b}].to_json
"[{\"a\":\"b\"}]"
```

Alternatively you could moneky patch `OpenStruct#as_json` as shown in hiroshi's answer:

```
require "ostruct"
class OpenStruct
  def as_json(options = nil)
    @table.as_json(options)
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, the reason why I am doing that is I need to change the original hash structure (rename some fields, drop some others).

Comment: Works like a charm. If there is any better way of doing that, let me know: https://gist.github.com/1300921

Comment: Any downside to `to_h.as_json(options)` rather than referencing `@table`?  It seems safer to use the public interface, even if I'm subclassing Ostruct.

Answer (score 32):

Because [@table is a instance variable of OpenStruct](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/ostruct.rb#L88) and [Object#as_json returns Hash of instance variables](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L157).

In my project, I implemented OpenStruct#as_json to override the behaviour.

```
require "ostruct"
class OpenStruct
  def as_json(options = nil)
    @table.as_json(options)
  end
end
```

Comment: I have been looking to over-ride the `OpenStruct`'s `inspect` method all day now, and this is the only thing that has worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what I need! You saved my day! Thx

Comment: This causes arguement errors for me. I have `Failure` and `Success` classes that inherit from OpenStruct. To be clear, I'm sure this works with OpenStruct, but with my other classes that inherit from it it breaks. Where I call `new` on to pass attributes for access from my services.  It errors out where I dynamically pass attributes/values to the new method

Answer (score 15):

I get around the problem by subclassing OpenStruct like so:

```
class DataStruct < OpenStruct
  def as_json(*args)
    super.as_json['table']
  end
end
```

then you can easily convert to JSON like so:

```
o = DataStruct.new(a:1, b:DataStruct.new(c:3))
o.to_json
# => "{\"a\":1,\"b\":{\"c\":3}}"
```

Neat huh? So in answer to your question, you'd write this instead:

```
[{:a => :b}].collect {|x| DataStruct.new(x)}.to_json
```

giving you:

```
=> "[{\"a\":\"b\"}]"
```

### UPDATE FOR RUBY 2.7 (Feb 5, 2021)

```
require 'json'
require 'ostruct'

class OpenStruct
  def to_json
    to_hash.to_json
  end

  def to_hash
    to_h.map { |k, v|
      v.respond_to?(:to_hash) ? [k, v.to_hash] : [k, v]
    }.to_h
  end
end

o = OpenStruct.new(a:1, b:OpenStruct.new(c:3))
p o.to_json
```

Comment: Note I had to do `super['table']` to get this to work.

Comment: What makes this 'for Ruby 2.7' exactly?

Answer (score 7):

I found the other responses to be a tad confusing having landed here to just figure out how to turn my OpenStruct into a `Hash` or JSON. To clarify, you can just call `marshal_dump` on your `OpenStruct`.

```
$ OpenStruct.new(hello: :world).to_json
=> "{\"table\":{\"hello\":\"world\"}}"

$ OpenStruct.new(hello: :world).marshal_dump
=> {:hello=>:world}

$ OpenStruct.new(hello: :world).marshal_dump.to_json
=> "{\"hello\":\"world\"}"
```

I personally would be hesitant to monkey-patch `OpenStruct` unless you're doing it on a subclass, as it may have unintended consequences.

Comment: This is a better answer! I like it

Answer (score 4):

With ruby 2.1.2 you can use the following to get JSON without the table root element:

```
[{:a => :b}].collect {|x| OpenStruct.new(x).to_h}.to_json
 => "[{\"a\":\"b\"}]"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
openstruct_array.map(&:to_h).as_json
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that internally it's doing a `as_json` which creates a Hash with the table key (because as_json serializes all of the instance variables of the object too and `@table` is an instance var of OpenStruct) and then it's doing a `to_json` on that which stringifies it.

So, the easiest way is to first just use `to_h` (which doesn't serialize the instance variables) and then `to_json` on that. So:

`OpenStruct.new(x).to_h.json` or in your case `open_struct_array.map(&:to_h).to_json`