# Converting a nested OpenStruct to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, type-conversion, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.5

It seems to be pretty easy to create nested OpenStruct objects using JSON.parse:

```
JSON.parse( '{"a":{"b":0}}', object_class:OpenStruct )
#<OpenStruct a=#<OpenStruct b=0>>
```

Is there a simpler method of converting it back to json, without creating a recursive function (as demonstrated here: [Deep Convert OpenStruct to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092107/deep-convert-openstruct-to-json))?

Answer (score 0):

Calling OpenStruct#to_json on your struct should do it:

```
[2] pry(main)> JSON.parse('{"a":{"b":0}}', object_class:OpenStruct).to_json
=> "{\"a\":{\"b\":0}}"
```

And from plain irb `OpenStruct#to_json` does not work:

```
irb(main):003:0> require 'ostruct'
=> true
irb(main):004:0> require 'json'
=> true
irb(main):005:0> JSON.parse('{"a":{"b":0}}', object_class:OpenStruct).to_json
=> "\"#<OpenStruct a=#<OpenStruct b=0>>\""
```

ruby 2.5.3, rails 4.2.11.1

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for the response.  That's a good suggestion and something I tried; however, the result I get is `"{\"table\":{\"a\":{\"table\":{\"b\":0},\"modifiable\":true}},\"modifiable\":true}"`.  Perhaps I have done something wrong, but all I have seen to address that is to modify the `as_json` or `to_json`, since *table* is an instance of OpenStruct.  This is my output of your example: `"{\"table\":{\"key1\":{\"table\":{\"key2\":1}}}}"` -- might you have already modified your version of to_json?

Comment: @Mike No I modified nothing. Please update your question because I dont really understand what `tables` have to do with `OpenStruct` and your current question as it is. Specify your input and desired output

Comment: I want to avoid complicating the question.  This may be a rails-specific issue as I'm noticing different behavior between irb and rails console.  Please refer here for an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835047/collecting-hashes-into-openstruct-creates-table-entry/13777745 ; notice in the question asked, there's a *table* key when converting from OpenStruct.   In my version I'm also seeing a *modifiable* key (as listed in my comment above)

Comment: @Mike What version of ruby and rails are you running? Im doing it in rails console and I see no `table` keys. Same for an example from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835047/collecting-hashes-into-openstruct-creates-table-entry/13777745 question.
I have rails `4.2.11.1` and ruby `2.5.3`

Comment: ruby 2.5 / rails 5.1 (I used the rails-5 tag on the question, but it looks like I need to update the question for the ruby version)